# Capture Currency in Span Class, Divide by 12 Round up and Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency-formatting

I'm not very good at this and have tried last few days searching up and down for any kind of answer to help solve my problem.  I've only pieced together the below.  I would like to grab the generated span class value, / by 12, round up to the nearest penny and than display elsewhere on the same webpage.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

```js
const price = document.getElementsByClassName('price-value')[0].innerHTML;  // Price of item before tax


// Calculate total after tax to two decimal places
let totalPrice = price / 12;
totalPrice.toFixed(2);


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =totalPrice
```

```html
<span class="price-value model-price-value-sale">
         $1,349.95
        </span>
                <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert the price from currency to an actual number by:

```
Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""))
```

Then use the `Math.ceil()` function to round up.

So it will be like that:

```js
const price = document.getElementsByClassName('price-value')[0].innerHTML;  // Price of item before tax


// Calculate total after tax to two decimal places
//let totalPrice = Math.ceil(Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,"")) / 12);

let totalPrice = Math.round((Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,"")) / 12)* 100)/100;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =totalPrice
```

```html
<span class="price-value model-price-value-sale">
         $1,349.95
        </span>
                <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you!  How to get it to round to nearest penny?  for example 48.685 would round up to 48.69

Comment: @JasonFenn You can use: Use "Math.round(num * 100) / 100" (edited the answer with this)